# Textbox in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

Lately I have been programming an application in Visual Basic 2008, and on one of my Windows Application forms I have several text box forms, and with my code the way it is, none of them can be enabled, and they must all be set to Read Only.

Now if I put a big block of text in one of the Text Box's that extends past the parameters of the box, the scroll bar appears but doesn't scroll because of making it's enabled false. So here's my question, is there any way I can make the Text Box's scroll bar functional but still leaving the enabled set to false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `textbox1.Readonly = true` instead of `textbox1.enabled = false`. Then you can use the scrollbars.